# github with mac osx/xcode

Tags: xcode, github, gitignore

ALL,

I am not really familiar with Xcode and how it manages its files, so I need some help from you.

I created an Xcode project with some libraries and it was compiling. Now I'm trying to push the changes to the existing GitHub repository.

What I did:

```
git init
git add origin
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
Igors-MacBook-Air:dbhandler igorkorot$ git pull
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    dbhandler/Info.plist
    dbhandler/Info.plist.in
    dbhandler/Makefile.in
    dbhandler/UpgradeLog.XML
    dbhandler/_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport.css
    dbhandler/_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport.xslt
    dbhandler/_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport_Minus.gif
    dbhandler/_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport_Plus.gif
    dbhandler/chart.icns
    dbhandler/chart.ico
    dbhandler/chart.r
    dbhandler/chart.xpm
    dbhandler/descrip.mms
    dbhandler/doc.cpp
    dbhandler/doc.h
    dbhandler/doc.icns
    dbhandler/doc.ico
    dbhandler/doc.r
    dbhandler/doc.xpm
    dbhandler/docview.bkl
    dbhandler/docview.cpp
    dbhandler/docview.h
    dbhandler/docview.r
    dbhandler/docview.rc
    dbhandler/docview_vc7.vcproj
    dbhandler/docview_vc8.vcproj
    dbhandler/docview_vc9.sln
    dbhandler/docview_vc9.vcproj
    dbhandler/docview_vc9.vcxproj
    dbhandler/docview_vc9.vcxproj.filters
    dbhandler/docview_vc9.vcxproj.user
    dbhandler/mainframe.cpp
    dbhandler/mainframe.h
    dbhandler/makefile.bcc
    dbhandler/makefile.gcc
    dbhandler/makefile.unx
    dbhandler/makefile.vc
    dbhandler/makefile.vms
    dbhandler/notepad.icns
    dbhandler/notepad.ico
    dbhandler/notepad.xpm
    dbhandler/rcdefs.h
    dbhandler/res/blank.cur
    dbhandler/res/bullseye.cur
    dbhandler/res/cdrom.ico
    dbhandler/res/colours.bmp
    dbhandler/res/computer.ico
    dbhandler/res/cross.cur
    dbhandler/res/csquery.bmp
    dbhandler/res/database.xpm
    dbhandler/res/drive.ico
    dbhandler/res/file1.ico
    dbhandler/res/floppy.ico
    dbhandler/res/folder1.ico
    dbhandler/res/folder2.ico
    dbhandler/res/hand.cur
    dbhandler/res/index.png
    dbhandler/res/magnif1.cur
    dbhandler/res/odbc.png
    dbhandler/res/odbc1.png
    dbhandler/res/odbc1.xpm
    dbhandler/res/pbrush.cur
    dbhandler/res/pencil.cur
    dbhandler/res/pntleft.cur
    dbhandler/res/pntright.cur
    dbhandler/res/removble.ico
    dbhandler/res/roller.cur
    dbhandler/res/sample.ico
    dbhandler/res/std.ico
    dbhandler/sample.rc
    dbhandler/view.cpp
    dbhandler/view.h
    dbhandler/viewbase.cpp
    dbhandler/viewbase.h
    dbhandler/wx.rc
    dbinterface/ReadMe.txt
    dbinterface/SQLite/sqlite3.h
    dbinterface/SQLite/sqlite3ext.h
    dbinterface/database.h
    dbinterface/dbinterface.sdf
    dbinterface/dbinterface.sln
    dbinterface/dbinterface.suo
    dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj
    dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj.filters
    dbinterface/dbinterface.vcxproj.user
    dbinterface/stdafx.cpp
    dbinterface/stdafx.h
    dbinterface/targetver.h
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Most of those files comes from the Windows/Linux projects. However there some files that are Xcode-specific.

Now, after I got this error, I tried to do this:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:dbhandler igorkorot$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 87 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
    Build/
    dbhandler/
    dbhandlerTests/
    dbinterface/
    dbloader/
    dialogs/
    odbc_lib/
    sqlite_lib/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So what do I do? How do I add the Xcode-specific files/folders and which one should go to .gitignore file to be kept untracked?

Thank you for the information and hopefully I didn't screw up my project in Xcode.

Comment: Broadly speaking, your local `master` has diverged  from the version on GitHub.  How did you get these local files and how long ago was that?

Comment: It looks like you have local untracked files which however are _tracked_  on GitHub.  Git is telling you that the remote `master` would overwrite these files if it completes the merge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I just initialised the GitHub repo on Mac. But the code itself on Mac was there since a long time. I just become tired of copying the code over the network. So if I do "git pull" my local files will be overwritten? That's fine - I made some changes on the Windows/Linux and want to bring the code up to speed on Mac.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, also I'd like to start tracking Mac-specific files in the local and remote repositories.

Comment: If you want to keep your changes, then you should commit those files which would be overwritten and then do the `git pull`.  You may get merge conflicts, but nothing should be unexpectedly overwritten.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, so I should add all those files from the error list, commit them to a local repository, and then do "git pull"? Or just add them without committing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, also, which files are safe to add to ".gitignore"?

Comment: The files that generated the "overwritten" error can't simply be added to gitignore because they are already part of the remote repository.